# capitalisation and list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, capitalization

I have a question about the list of acronyms.
I am using the `glossaries` package and create my acronyms using:

```
\newacronym{Repo}{Repo}{Repurchase Agreement}
```

For this example, I would like to have Repo starting with a capital letter in the List of Acronyms, but with a small letter in the text.

Kind regards
Jannik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the extension package [glossaries-extra](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) and use the category attributes `glossname` (for the display of the `name` field in the glossary) and, optionally, `glossdesc` (for the display of the `description` field in the glossary):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronyms]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossname}{firstuc}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{title}

\newacronym{Repo}{repo}{repurchase agreement}

\begin{document}

First use: \gls{Repo}. 

Next use: \gls{Repo}.

Explicitly case-change: \Gls{Repo}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

Since `\newacronym` automatically sets the `category` to `acronym`, this modification will affect any entries defined with `\newacronym` but not any entries that are defined using other commands, such as `\newabbreviation` or `\newglossaryentry` (unless the `category` is set explicitly).